# Ejabberd has high CPU usage, and shows inactive users as connected

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

We have 3 Ejabberd nodes hosting a chat platform. Each night we run load tests on our platform with a large number of users. The load tests are run using a scripted headless browser. Each test ends the session after it is completed.

After the load tests have completed, Ejabberd's cpu usage remains very high. The list of connected users shows the user id's of the test users as connected - even though they have been inactive for hours.

We are a little stumped as to where to go to debug this. We have tried using:

```
  mod_ping:
    send_pings: true
    ping_interval: 300
    timeout_action: kill
```

But this made no difference.

We have tried to run etop from within the debug console, but this returns nothing.

Any insight on where to start investigating would be greatly appreciated.